# URL redirection using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, redirect

My website is deployed and running on apache server from enomcentral hosting environment with only limited access so i can't change any configuration setting except htaccess file. Also another application running on tomcat in different domain server with full admin access.

**e.g** - `www.example.com` is running on enomcental. and tomcat application running on `www.abc.com/xyz`.

I want to access tomcat application, running on different domain ,using the url `www.example.com/xyz`.

so when I enter Url `www.example.com/xyz` the URL remains same but the content should be comes form w`ww.abc.com/xyz` i.e., `tomcat server example/`

URL redirection changing the browser URL. 
I can only change ion .htaccess file.
`mod_jk.so` configuration not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is mod_proxy, if enabled,

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

then, this rule will work.

```
RewriteRule ^xyz$ http://www.abc.com/xyz [P]
```

P means proxy, [docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

But if mod_proxy is disabled, then could you make the /xyz point to some cgi(e.g proxy.php), which is under your control, and make the cgi read content from http://www.abc.com/xyz?